Is it possible to tell Cloudflare Mirage to ignore an img element?
Mirage by Cloudflare is being used on a website that I am contributing content to. I cannot disable it, and I do not have access to manage the settings. I discovered that the mirage script is stripping the style="..." attribute from <img> tags, which causes buggy behavior in a javascript library I use (OpenSeadragon). See related github issue here: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/2641
I have discovered that if I defer creation of my OpenSeadragon viewer by 15 ms, the problem goes away (i.e. the injected <img> elements are left alone). It would be nice if there is was a tag I could add to the initial HTML to instruct mirage to ignore an element. However, I haven't found anything on the cloudflare docs other than a bunch of unanswered stale posts on their forums asking related questions.
Does anyone know if this is possible, or is there documentation that it is explicitly not possible to do this? Is the technique of deferring creation of these elements the best I can do?
